# Instancias de sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

disculpen  ayuda  por favor con esto

si tengo  una instancia con varias tablas  y se daño, bueno y cree otra instancia para poder crear una nueva base de datos que necesito y que no puedo  acceder por la instancia dañada

según intente restaurar un backup de la base de datos que necesito en la nueva  instancia pero me marca un error  diciendo que ya existe esa base de datos 
entonces mis dudas serian:

1)las 2 instancias  están conectadas solo en las bases de datos (o sea que si hago algo en una base de datos en las 2 instancias afecta)

2)pero si elijo borrar una instancia no afecta a la otra o si

3)si me avisa que ya existe ¿porque no puedo ver la la base de datos en la instancia nueva?

gracias

Comment: ¿Qué error te sale?

Comment: gracias  por tu respuesta a amigo   el mensaje que me salio  era la base de datos ya existes que si quiero sobre escribirla o remplazarla